# Can someone explain how the constructor is being used in the following lines of code

Tags: java, constructor

I mean the `Quack()` and `FlyWithWings()` constructors in the `MallardDuck` class below. This may be something simple but I just haven't come across constructors being used this way. The code is an example of a strategy pattern.

```
public class MallardDuck extends Duck {

    public MallardDuck() {
        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("I'm a real Mallard duck");
    }
}

public class Quack implements QuackBehavior {
    public void quack() {
        System.out.println("Quack");
    }
}

public class FlyWithWings implements FlyBehavior {
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("I'm flying!!");
    }
}

public abstract class Duck {
    FlyBehavior flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior quackBehavior;

    public Duck() {
    }

    public void setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior fb) {
        flyBehavior = fb;
    }

    public void setQuackBehavior(QuackBehavior qb) {
        quackBehavior = qb;
    }

    abstract void display();

    public void performFly() {
        flyBehavior.fly();
    }

    public void performQuack() {
        quackBehavior.quack();
    }

    public void swim() {
        System.out.println("All ducks float, even decoys!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does confuse you about these constructors?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the MallardDuck constructor to call super();
and move the initialization in the super class Duck to be

```
public abstract class Duck {
FlyBehavior flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior quackBehavior;

    public Duck() {
  quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
    }
..
}
```

and

```
 public MallardDuck() {
super();
    }
```

And for better encapsulation you should define `flyBehavior`, `quackBehavior` as protected in `Duck` class

Comment: The duck constructor should take a `FlyBehavior` and `QuackBehavior` argument. When the duck is created without arguments it should call `this(new Quack(), new FlyWithWings());`

Comment: Maybe he don't need to pass the `QuackBehavior` and `FlyBehavior` to be only initialized from the super class. Its all depends on the usage

Comment: Thanks alot everyone your answers really help.

Comment: Welcome, can you considered as an answer or not yet

Answer (score 0):

`Quack()` and `FlyWithWings()` are default constructors. They're added by default and executed when you call them with

```
        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
```

The constructor in `Duck` is invoked when you initialize a class that extends `Duck` class.

By executing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MallardDuck();
}
```

you will invoke Duck's constructor (that actually doesn't do anything).

Comment: That's not true. Quack() and FlyWithWings() *are* calls to the respective constructors, but they're just not explicitly defined.

Comment: I know, i think the OP edited the question a couple of times confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not define a constructor for a class, the Java compiler will create it for you. However, the default constructor doesn't contain anything useful, only a call to `super()`, which is the constructor for the superclass.

In your case, you're calling the implicitly defined constructors for the Quack and FlyWithWings classes. These constructors only contain a call to the superclass, which in your case, is the class Object since they don't extend any other classes. (By the way, the Object class's constructor *actually* does nothing).

So basically, all you're doing is instantiating an essentially empty object simply to use its `quack()` method, and the same for the `fly()` method.